# Removing the ugly border rendering on box-shadow in mobile Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, border, css

The problem is following - on mobile Chrome (Google Nexus 5) my box-shadows have an ugly visible border, instead of a seamless transition into background underneath. Is there any way to correct that? It's not visible on any of the desktop browsers. Even Chrome Device Emulator displays it properly.

Any ideas? Prefixing does not help... I though about substituting the shadows with linear-gradient background, but it requires additional, non-semantic markup and is hella tricky in comparison to comma-separated shadows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRc3C.png

EDIT: as mentioned in comments (thanks, @vlrprbttst) - **it's not an inset shadow**.

I have a fixed header and footer, which need to drop shadow on the background. The problem is, I can't really change the layout, I need to modernize it. Previous designer used pngs as backgrounds, I figured that it's gonna be better if I replace all images with CSS3 to reduce the amount of HTTP requests. Now I get complaints that it's ugly - justified ones.

Comment: code needed. is the box-shadow inset?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention - **it's not inset**:
`box-shadow: 0px 0px 180px #666, 0px 0px 25px #888;`